# Waiting for request django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, redis

I need to send a request from my React client to the Django server. Processing this request may take about 30 seconds, due to the calculations in the function. What is the best approach to handle this case? Currently, I opt for celery+redis or WebSockets, but maybe there is a simpler approach?

Comment: Just send the request and wait until you get the response.  30 seconds is longish for a web request, but it shouldn't be long enough to get a timeout.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is that heroku which is my current provider, has timeout about 20 seconds, something like that, generally i want cleaner way than waiting

Comment: celery + redis would be the easiest way to get long process executed in the background. Any reason for you to not consider this?

Comment: Yes, I decided to user celery + redis, thanks